# Assign multiple public ssh keys to user definitions with authorized_key module in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

**Question:**

Using Ansible, how can I set multiple public-key files (`.pub`) to be deployed in a user's `authorized_keys` file instead of using a single file containing a list of public ssh-keys?

---

**Scenario and requirements:**

- I have multiple public ssh-keys stored as `.pub` files on a central location
- I want to create new users from a `vars` file
- each user shall have (none/one specific/multiple) public ssh-keys from the selection of `.pub` files deployed to their respective `authorized_keys` file
- the list of deployed `.pub` files can change due to:

  - content of `.pub` file has changed due to eg. compromised private key
  - user in `vars` file shall have additional public key files assigned
- I don't want to go through a "list" file for each user to replace a key

---

**Currently deployed:**

vars-file (`vars/users.yml`):

```
users:
  - username: "bob"
    sshkey: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/ssh_keys/bob.keys') }}"
    ...
  - username: "alice"
    sshkey: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/ssh_keys/alice.keys') }}"
    ...
```

contents of `bob.keys`:

```
ssh-rsa admin-ssh-key= admin
ssh-rsa support-a-ssh-key= support-a
ssh-rsa bobs-ssh-key= hi im bob
```

contents of `alice.keys`:

```
ssh-rsa admin-ssh-key= admin
ssh-rsa alice-ssh-key= hi im alice
ssh-rsa accounting-clerk-ssh-key= checking your progress
```

ansible role main.yml file:

```
 - name: Add SSH keys
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.username }}"
    state: "{{ item.sshkeystate }}"
    key: "{{ item.sshkey }}"
    exclusive: yes
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
  tags: [add ssh keys]
```

---

**Problem Scenario:**

- `support-a`'s ssh key got compromised and all users having that public key in their `authorized_keys` file need to be replaced with the new public key
- I need to (`sed`) through all `keys` files and replace the compromised public key with the new one

---

**I tried:**

vars-file:

```
users:
  - username: "bob"
  sshkey:
    - "{{ lookup('file', 'files/ssh_keys/admin.pub') }}"
    - "{{ lookup('file', 'files/ssh_keys/support_a.pub') }}"
    - "{{ lookup('file', 'files/ssh_keys/bob.pub') }}"
  ...
  - username: "alice"
  sshkey:
    - "{{ lookup('file', 'files/ssh_keys/admin.pub') }}"
    - "{{ lookup('file', 'files/ssh_keys/alice.pub') }}"
    - "{{ lookup('file', 'files/ssh_keys/accounting_clerk.pub') }}"
```

However, I'm getting this error when executing the ansible role:
`"msg": "invalid key specified: ['ssh-rsa admin-ssh-key= admin', 'ssh-rsa support-a-ssh-key= support-a', 'ssh-rsa bobs-ssh-key= hi im bob']"`

I also tried something along the lines of this ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/54079374 ) solution but I guess the scenario and requirements are a bit different and there is nothing to `selectattr()` in my scenario (I think).

---

Can anyone point me to how to solve this or am I going in a completely wrong direction?
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best I can tell, the only part that differs in your playbook from the one you linked to is the `"\n".join()` part, which folds the list into one text block. As ansible correctly points out, you are providing a `list[str]` to an attribute that expects `str`

I don't believe in your circumstance you need to use `selectattr` or any filtering, because you want all the keys all the time. Thus:

```yaml
- name: Add SSH keys
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.username }}"
    state: "{{ item.sshkeystate }}"
    key: '{{ item.sshkey | join("\n") }}'
    exclusive: yes
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
  tags: [add ssh keys]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!
I think I'm getting the hang of it and just found some more resources to dig into: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

Comment: After I change `key: '{{ item.sshkey | join("\n") }}'` to `"{{ item.keys | join('\n') }}"`, it starts to work.